# How many passes of radix sort are required to sort an array of integers if we are limited to using 256 buckets on any pass?

Tags: data-structures

. How many passes of radix sort are required
to sort an array of integers if we are limited
to using 256 buckets on any pass?

Comment: That depends on the size of the integers

Comment: For the question itself it doesn't give any integer values. So would I generate an Array that would hold some integer values for the purpose of the proof ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

256 buckets mean that you can sort out one byte in one pass (a byte is 8 bits, `(expt 2 8)` is 256, so one byte can take on 256 different values).  You need to compare the integers entirely.  You thus need a number of passes equal to the number of bytes required to represent the largest integer in the array.